# Change height to all a element in a div with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a ul tag with an ID and on a click of a button I want to change height and display of the div itself and same for each a tag inside that div.

I have trouble select each a tag and changing their style.

I want to use just javascript.

**My mark-up**

```
 <ul id="mobile_nav" >
     <a href="about.html" class="images" ><li><p>about me</p></li></a>
     <a href="work.html" class="images"><li><p>work</p></li></a>
     <a href="letstalk.html" class="images"><li   ><p>let's talk</p></li></a>
 </ul>
```

**My js**

```
       var but = document.getElementById('mobile_menu')
        but.onclick=function() {
                var ul = document.getElementById('mobile_nav')
            var a = document.getElementById('mobile_nav').getElementsByTagName('a');
            console.log(ul) //SEEMS TO WORK
            console.log(a) //AS ABOVE
                console.log(typeof(a)) // THAT S AN OBJECT
            ul.style.display="block" // THAT S WORK
            ul.style.height="auto";//WORKING
          //TRYING TO GO THOUGHT MY OBJECT AND CHANGE HEIGHT
                for (var x in a) {
               a[x].style.height="42px";//IT SAID PROPERTY OF UNDEFINED
               console.log('done')// IT S PRINTING THAT AS MANY AD MY A TAGS
               console.log(a[x].)// NUMBER OF A TAGS IN MY DIV
    }
    }
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, therefore your DOM will be different than your HTML would imply and any JavaScript based upon that HTML/DOM will likely not work. The *only* valid child element of either `ul` or `ol` elements is an `li`.

Comment: so I can't put a tag before <li> thats what u saying?

Comment: You can't wrap an `li` with an `a` is what I'm saying.

Comment: gotcha u....make sense...I thought that was a bit of an hack! LOL cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you wrote, you find all elements you are after with:

```
var elements = document.getElementById('mobile_nav').getElementsByTagName('a');
```

The result of above is `NodeList`. You can traverse it like that:

```
for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++){
   elements[i].style.height = "25px";
}
```

Comment: why u are using for loop ? a NodeList isn't an object?

Comment: You can't use a foreach function on a NodeList. 
For more information you can take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList

Comment: When I did console.log(typeof(a)) came out as object so I didn't try the for loop but it seems working...I d be happy to know the reason tho

Comment: @AlexG_1010100101 Look at link Hatsjoem provided. (NodeList is a basic interface for accessing DOM elements)